# Hiding drives in windows 7 come back after restart

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, window

I am hiding drives in window explorer using this idea

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/hide-drives-from-your-computer-in-windows-vista/

But every time i restart or log off and log on then they come back.

How can i permanently hide them

Comment: After you restart or log off and on again, are the registry changes gone?

Comment: @user1721949 - The simple solution would be to have a scheduled task that is ran that makes these modifications when the user logs into the account.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the Method 3 from this article: http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/155795-drive-hide-unhide.html

Just try the Method 1 :)

Using the Local Group Policy Editor

1. Open the all users, specific users or groups, or all users except administrators Local Group Policy Editor for how you want this policy applied.
2. In the left pane, click on User Configuration, Administrative Templates, Windows Components, and Windows Explorer. (See screenshot below)
   Drive - Hide or Unhide-group_policy.jpg
3. In the right pane, right click on Hide these specified drives in My Computer and click on Properties. (See screenshot above)
4. To Unhide All Drives
   A) Select (dot) Disabled or Not Configured and click on OK. (See screenshot below step 5C)

B) Go to step 6.
5. To Hide a Drive or Combination of Drives
A) Select (dot) Enabled.

B) Click on the drop down arrow and select the drive or combination of drives option that you want to set as restricted (hidden). (See screenshot below)
NOTE: Even though the options say Restrict, it is to Hide the drive(s).

C) Click on OK.
Drive - Hide or Unhide-properties.jpg
6. Close the Local Group Policy Editor window. Your done.

Comment: it says A B C D ONLY ,  i have 12 drives and i want to hide 6

Comment: @user1721949 - Are you against restricting all drives? Make sure your actual system says that not and you are not just going off what is displayed in the screenshot